# How is the number of spawned users calculated when using the fixed_count attribute

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, locust

I have locust file with following users:

```
class UserA(HttpUser):
    weight = 115

    @task
    def ping(self):
        ...

    @task
    def view_items(self):
        ...


class UserB(HttpUser):
    weight = 83

    @task
    def ping(self):
        self.client.get("/ping")

    @task(3)
    def view_items(self):
        ...


class UserC(HttpUser):
    weight = 1

    @task
    def ping(self):
        ...

    @task(3)
    def view_items(self):
        ...


class UserD(HttpUser):
    weight = 1

    @task
    def ping(self):
        ...

    @task(3)
    def view_items(self):
        ...
```

When I run locust tests for 200 users, then it creates as I expected:

```
{"UserA": 115, "UserB": 83, "UserC": 1, "UserD": 1} (200 total users)
```

But I want to use `fixed_count` attribute for `UserC` and `UserD`, because I also want to run tests for 400 users for example, where only one instance of `UserC` and `UserD` will be spawned.
When I replace `weight = 1` to `fixed_count=1` in `UserC` and `UserD`, then users strangely rebalanced:

```
{"UserA": 119, "UserB": 79, "UserC": 1, "UserD": 1} (200 total users)
```

Why is there a bias towards `UserA`? How can I keep original count of spawned users, and still use `fixed_count`?